# String to time conversion error in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, strptime

I have certain time values in excel as :

#### Data:

```
932    
1253    
5
```

#### Coversions:

When trying to process them as a time string I get:

```
TIME_FMT= "%H%M"

datetime.strptime('932',TIME_FMT).time()
# Output : datetime.time(9, 32)

datetime.strptime('1253',TIME_FMT).time()
# Output : datetime.time(12, 53)

datetime.strptime('5',TIME_FMT).time()
# Output : ValueError: time data '5' does not match format '%H%M'
```

How can I catch such exceptional values for normal processing?

I understand that `5` does not match the format `"%H%M"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you add some leading `'0'`s to the string, the conversion can proceed like:

#### Code:

```
def from_time_string(time_string):
    TIME_FMT = "%H%M"
    leading = '0' * (3 - len(time_string))
    return dt.datetime.strptime(leading + time_string, TIME_FMT).time()
```

#### Test Code:

```
for i in ('932', '1253', '5'):
    print(from_time_string(i))
```

#### Results:

```
09:32:00
12:53:00
00:05:00
```